# ko.contextFor without using a specific DIV element to get to the context model?

Tags: knockout.js

In some places (not much) I need to get to the context.
I can get it to work like this:
var context = ko.contextFor($('#systemTreeDiv')[0]).$root.model;

But, my question is how can I avoid hard-coding an element like this? in this case #systemTreeDiv?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to avoid it. If there was a way you would not be in the need to use "contextFor" in the first place.

The reason you are probably needing this contextFor call is exactly because you have no access to the model programmatically from your executing context and you can also not pass the relevant element as a parameter, otherwise you would be able to just pass the needed model as a parameter/dependency to the code that is needing it, instead of getting the model through contextFor.

You will have to restructure your code so that you avoid the need to get the context this way by passing the required model as a parameter ( or at least the element that is bound onto so you don't hard code it).

As long as you do not pass either the model itself or at least the element, the only real solution still remains to restructure your code...

An actual answer is really hard since the question is so broad, you are referring to "some places" but each of those could have a different answer as to how to get the context to/from that place in your code base.